# Listing languages in CV

Tags: cv, language

I study in a field that is not related to languages. Should I put languages that I can speak into my CV? Other than English, I can speak my native language, and two other languages that I've learned through classes (at an intermediate level).

Might it be seen as irrelevant and hurt my CV?

Comment: What level? Faculty positions, postdoc, grad school applicant? This will be context dependent but I would have a hard time imagining why speaking an extra language would be used against you, but in most cases it won't help you either.

Comment: @WetLabStudent PhD student putting CV on website

Comment: Details this small really doesn't matter all that much until you are actually applying for jobs. And even in that case I don't see putting languages hurting you. Go ahead and list them.

Comment: I'm just stating the obvious, but here is one case in which this information is relevant: if you are applying for a job in nation X, being proficient with X's national language is a plus because it means it will be easier for you to fit in with the group and the locals, and also to do some teaching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely acceptable to display this kind of information on your CV and I can't think of any situation where it can hurt you professionally or socially. However, I would not recommend putting this kind of information on the resume you send out for specific positions (or even proposals) ***unless it is important to the job (or proposal) you are applying to***. 
I say this because your CV is a more complete profile of your professions and abilities and listing another language (preferably near the bottom somewhere above hobbies) will not be deemed as a bad thing and in many cases it can actually have a positive effect on how others perceive you. However, a resume is more tailored for specific needs and listing irrelevant information can always have a negative impact on the opposite person.

**EDIT:** In my personal line of work/study (computer science), speaking another language usually does not help you directly, but is is seen (by many) as an indication of your potential abilities. Speaking another language (and speaking it well) is not an easy task and those who are capable of doing so, show above-average motivation and determination.

Comment: +1 for "shows above-average motivation and determination".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put it. I've gotten positions for strange reasons before (as in: "many of the other candidates were qualified too, but I chose you because you had additional quality X"). Maybe your future employer speaks that language and wants to speak it with you. Or maybe they're just impressed by polyglotism. In any case, it can't hurt.